# android cardview с подсказкой всплывающей снизу

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.
Не понял в [официальной документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/lists-cards.html), что такое подсказка.
Это область после cardview, которая появляется при нажатии на него(cardview)?
Т.е. нажали и снизу выплыло дополнительная область, где наш комментарий или еще что-нибудь.

Если нет, то есть ли такая возможность сделать это?

Comment: В android не принят формат, с "выплывающими" дополнительными областями каких-либо `View` для подсказок. Здесь для этих целей используется `Toast` и , с некоторого времени, `SnackBar`. Не рекомендую вам отклоняться от гайдлайнов в кустарщину, пользователи, как правило, это не оценят.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это особенности перевода. В русской версии "Card" перевели, почему-то, как "Подсказка". В [английской версии](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) статьи есть только слово "Card"

Всплывающая снизу строка с инфой и кнопкой это `Snackbar`. Вызвать его можно так:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(VIEW_IN_BOOTOM_OF_WHICH_SNACKBAR_WILL_ARRIVE, "SnackBar", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
snackbar.show();
```

Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но еще нужно добавить `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`